# Java - Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ftp

I am trying to implement basic FTP client using Java Spring Boot and I ran into this problem and I wanted to ask you, if you had any experience with it.

I let my Tomcat server running and I put my computer to sleep mode, after about 3 hours, I wake the PC and server was still running, so I tried to call the endpoint (this endpoint should check connection and then upload the file to FTP server), but I get this exception message:

> Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Do you think that this was caused because the PC was sleeping for a long time and it has lost the connection or should it be something else? If so, how should I handle this case?

When I restart the server, file uploaded normally.

Here is my endpoint class:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            FTPClient ftpClient = Connection.getFtpClient();

            if (!Connection.isConnected()) { Connection.connect(); }

            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/AiDisk_a1/usb/");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
            ftpClient.storeFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), inputStream);

            return "Status: " + ftpClient.getReplyString();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Endpoint exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            return "Endpoint exception: " + ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `logout()` and `disconnect()`.

```
logout() throws IOException
```

Logout of the FTP server by sending the QUIT command.

```
 } finally {
    ftp.logout();
    ftp.disconnect();
  }
```

You must first connect to the server with connect before doing anything, and finally disconnect after you're completely finished interacting with the server.
[FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: So after I catch this exception, I should call logout and disconnect in finally block? But this should be in try catch block aswell.